# How would I go about accessing the iPhone filesystem via Java?

Tags: java, iphone, ipad, filesystems

I was wondering how such a thing is possible to do? I am aware Java isn't exactly the most hardware language available, but is there a way to access the devices filesystem? If so could you link me to some helpful information and how I would go about doing so?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Write a java to objective-c compiler. But get good lawyers to defend yourself against Oracle and Apple

Comment: Is this for a Java application running on the desktop that would browse the filesystem of a connected device?  There is no Java VM for the iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

Apple and Java don't mix. I don't believe there will be a VM available in the near future.

Comment: No I do not need a JVM on iPhone. Just connection via USB via my desktop computer.